# Replace multiple values from string in numbers sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey Friends I want to replace 1 to 'asd' and 10 to 'asdddd' in a string like 1and2and10 but it replace it to 'asd'and2and'asd'0 in sql server please help.

Thank you

Comment: share whatever you have tried yet. some query or anything other.

Comment: Please add some sample data and also anything you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('1and2and10' , '10', 'asdddd'), '1', 'asd')
```

or with table:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(myColumn , '10', 'asdddd'), '1', 'asd') FROM myTable
```

Comment: I am not sure if this will be the string every time and number can go up to 100 in this case so I can not take risk of hard codes

Comment: @Soul_Hunter Then update the question and include all cases. What you saying now wasn't mentioned in question.

Comment: I am saying that there can be a case when (1and2and3and4)or(3and29and1)